# Execute default action in SQL Server's insted of triggers?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way in a INSTEAD OF trigger to just cause the default action?

For instance write a query like this:

```
BEGIN

    IF <some rule>
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        EXIT
    END

    /* Long, boring, DDL dependant query ...
    INSERT INTO
    ...
    ... ...
    ... ... ... -_-'
    */

    // A simple statement that does the job!!
    <default insertion> 
END
```

My goal is to check some business rule and only if the check passes insert (or update/delete) without having to rewrite the whole statement which would break if the table's structure was to change.

Comment: You can call(execute) SP from trigger.

Comment: Are you sure that `<some rule>` can't be implemented in some declarative way, such that the triggers don't have to be written at all?

Comment: <some rule> is checking that amongst all rows (existing + inserted) there's no two rows which dates overlaps. If I do it using CHECK + user function, it will lead to RBAR (as far as I Know).

Comment: @HamletHakobyan if I call a SP that makes the insertion, SQL Server will complain - INSTEAD OF triggers do not support direct recursion. The trigger execution failed.

Comment: Where you see recursion?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no.  In some vanilla cases you can get away with using `*` instead of listing the fields, but you probably shouldn't do that anyway.

SQL is not an OO language or environment and does not have the same level of code re-usability as they do.  Consequently, there are many common cases where the right thing to do is repetitive and even redundant. In short, DRY does not always apply in SQL.

In particular, it almost never applies with respect to the impact of DDL changes.  So for DDL changes, it is best to accept that the Edit Sensitivity of correct code is always going to be greater than one.  You are just going to have to change things in more than one place.